# git incorrectly recognizes a new file as moved from another file

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I use IDEA editor and add a file to my project to be managed by git, since there is another file in the current project, which is very similar to that file, git recognizes that file as moved from another file, how can I make git recognize that file as a new file?

I hope that in the future git doesn't recognize newly added files as having been moved from another file.

Comment: I think that only happens if you also removed the other file. Then git might recognise the removed file, and an identically-named file in another directory, for example, as the file having been moved. So, did you remove the other (original) file?